# Some questions on implementation choices in Corda such as log4j2 and repositories MavenCentral Jcenter

Tags: corda

Quick check on these two questions regarding some design choices in Corda:

1. All 3 of these repositories are required in the build.gradle: 'jcenter()', 'mavenCentral()' and 'maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }'.

   a) Why is Corda dependent on a github snapshot (jitpack)

   b) why is everything not in both jcenter and mavenCentral? why is some 
         parts in one and others in another? What is the criteria where the 
         repositories are handle in jcenter vs/or mavenCentral?
2. Lots of examples seem to be using log4j2 (not even log4j) but the core seems to be using slf4j. Is there any technical reason for this choice over logback for instance?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Corda but regarding question 2, I assume that the performance benefits of Log4j2 may have been a factor: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html

Comment: Which examples are using log4j2?

Answer (score 2):

Jitpack is used to create a dependency on a special fork of the CRaSH shell (e.g. https://github.com/crashub/crash/commit/cadb53544fbb3c0fb901445da614998a6a419488).

Answer (score 2):

1a) The Corda team started using Jitpack to compile some forked repos some time ago (some dependencies just had bugs that needed a quick patch, some are a full fork). The dependencies that are hard forked (eg; crash) will be put into the Corda artifactory at some point in the near future, and those that were quick releases to fix an urgent bug will be changed back to rely on the upstream release binaries.

1b) Please report any missing binaries to the [Corda Slack](https://cordaledger.slack.com) or [issue tracker](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues) on GitHub. Jcenter will be fully featured because we upload there first and publish to central after. Due to the manual nature this sometimes goes wrong. We have begun switching to automating these.

I believe that 2 isn't appropriate for StackOverflow and belongs in the Corda slack's #design channel.

Comment: SLF4J is a logging abstraction layer which has Log4J2 behind it. One shouldn't be talking directly to Log4J2 for normal logging operations.